# Compressing a foreach loop to linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

So I have three lists:

```
// Members stores all non-sorted member objects
var Members = new List<Member>();

// Years stores all the expected graduation years I want to compare
var Years = new List<int>();

// Sorted will contain all of the members that have a matching year
var Sorted = new List<Member>();
```

I am using a foreach loop to sort these values

```
foreach (var m in Members)
{
    foreach (var y in Years)
    {
       if (m.ExpectedGraduationYear == y)
       {
           Sorted.Add(m);
       }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to compress this into a single linq statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, something like this:

```
Sorted = Members.Where(m => Years.Any(y => y == m.ExpectedGraduationYear)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use such LINQ query:

```
Sorted = (from m in Members
         join y in Years
         on m.ExpectedGraduationYear equals y
         select m).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Members.Where(m => Years.Contains(m.ExpectedGraduationYear)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var Sorted = (from m in Members 
              from y in Years 
              where m.ExpectedGraduationYear == y select m).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Sorted = (from m in Members from y in Years.Where(y => m.ExpectedGraduationYear == y)
                              select m).ToList();
```